# DBCC - consistency errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a error like `Table error: Object ID 3, index ID 1, Page is missing a reference from previous page`.

DBCC results for 'RKB'.

```
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 3, index ID 1, partition ID 196608, alloc unit ID 196608 (type In-row data). 
Page (1:452) is missing a reference from previous page (1:16153).
Possible chain linkage problem.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 1 consistency errors in table 'sys.sysrscols' (object ID 3).
Msg 7995, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Database 'RKB': consistency errors in system catalogs prevent further DBCC checkdb processing.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 1 consistency errors in table '(Object ID 99)' (object ID 99).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 2 consistency errors in database 'RKB'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

I am try with DBCC CHECKDB (RKB, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS but my consistency errors not solved. How can I fix this error? can anyone help me?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I tried with DBCC CHECKDB (RKB, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS but my consistency errors not solved. How can I solved this error? can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try recreating or reloading the table. You can have more info on this link
http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/introductiontointegritychainlinkageproblems
But if you see frequent errors like this, you should check you I/O sub system.